# 1D Wave Equation on the Half Space

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

From Evans' PDE Book - we want to solve the 1D Wave Equation on the half-space

$$u_{tt}-u_{xx} = 0 \text{ in } \mathbb{R}_+ \times (0,  \infty)$$
$$u = g, u_t = h \text{ on } \mathbb{R}_+ \times \{t = 0\}$$
$$u = 0 \text{ on } \{x = 0\} \times (0, \infty)$$

Where $g$ and $h$ are given with $g(0) = h(0) = 0$.

It then goes on to perform an odd extension, and then you can apply D'alemberts Formula for the Wave Equation on the whole line.

My question is - why can't I use an even extension? Where does this break down if I do that? The calculations all seem to work fine (can do the extension and write down a formula after apply D'alemberts).

Comment: Wouldn't an even extension violate $u=0$ on $\{x=0\}\times (0,\infty)$?

Comment: @Martin could you explain why? Sorry there's just something simple I'm not seeing here. I'm imagining the x-t space and I'm not seeing the problem here

Comment: Imagine a standing wave. $x=0$ must be a fixed point, so the only even solution is $u=0$ everywhere